# 100 boxes, only 50 attempts

Tags: logical-deduction, strategy

There are 100 boxes in the room. In every box there is a note with some number from 1 to 100 (no repetitions).Person A comes into the room and checks all the boxes and notes inside them. He can (doesn't have to) choose 2 boxes and swap notes between them. After he finishes he exits the room. Person B comes to the room. He needs to find a note with some random number. In order to do it he can open only 50 boxes.

Question: how person A should switch 2 boxes in order to help person B to find the number? (person A doesn't know which note person B should find).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to beat Count Dracula](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23150/how-to-beat-count-dracula)
(this is actually marked as a duplicate of  https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/25558/32339 which is very similar to your question)

Comment: This is also essentially the [100 Prisoners' Names in Boxes](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/16/20814) puzzle, but where person A fixes things to make the solution strategy work in every case.